# Android Studio emulator - Takes ages to boot and system ui crashes each time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am using the android emulator within Android Studio and have tried lots of different devices. It takes 5 minutes plus to cold boot the first time and then the system ui crashes each time. After waiting for it the emulator is extremely slow.

Quick boot always fails as when attempted it times out after 7 seconds.

Emulator often brings up this error:

```
Emulator: Unable to open C:\Users\Sam\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_27_2.avd\data\misc\pstore\ps
```

[Emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHafA.png)

Comment: increase heap size.

Comment: @SantanuSur Increased significantly, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced a similar problem. If your emulator was working before this issue, maybe this will help:

In your `SDK manager` -> `SDK tools` check `intel x86emulator accelerator(HAXM installer)`.

If it is installed, uncheck it and apply After it is uninstalled, reinstall it!

I hope this helps! :)

[Example of what your `SDK tools` should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuDVr.png)

Comment: All installed. Tried reinstalling HAXM but no improvement.